# Insert pictures into whitespace in document

Tags: graphics, positioning

Okay, I'm not sure if this is even possible.

We're currently switching the layouting of our "Basics" university intro booklet from Scribus to LaTeX. A difficulty there is minimising white space after articles. In Scribus we'd manually place comics where white space occurs, but now we'd like to automate this process. One way I was thinking about would be to place a lot of those comics somewhere in the document and tell latex to put them where there's space (in the whitespace hopefully), but I'm neither sure how to do that nor if it even works.

So yeah, place pictures where whitespace was, basically it.

Comment: There are two possible approaches and it isn't clear which you want. It would help if you provided a small example document. You can use a _floating environment_ such as `figure` so that latex will move the image to get a good page break, this may loosely be described as minimising the white space at the breaks, but it would not produce the same breaks that would be produced without the figures. **Or** at forced page breaks at  section headings, you could inspect how full the previous page is and insert an image if there is more than some specified threshold

Comment: First, thanks for the answer David.
Both approaches sound usable, actually.
Can I also conditionally introduce forced page breaks? Then I'd make such a check after every article.
I'll work on providing an example document, let's see what I can come up with.

Comment: @peacememories any update? Have you solved this?